# Updating order totals in frontend checkout/admin order view - M2

Tags: magento, magento2, checkout

On checkout page I need to update order totals and remove VAT from total after validating the VAT field (the validation is done in the controller). Also the prices need to be saved on order view in backend.

I already tried to make the update by custom js and it's working fine in frontend, but doesn't save on order view in backend

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/resource-url-manager',
    'mage/storage',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-payment-information',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/totals',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/full-screen-loader',

    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-totals',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/cart/totals-processor/default'
], function ($, quote, urlManager,storage, getPaymentInformationAction, totals, fullscreenLoader, 
    getTotalsAction) {
    'use strict';

    return function (removeTax, tax) {
        var payload = {
            addressInformation: {
                shipping_address: quote.shippingAddress(),
                billing_address: quote.billingAddress(),
                shipping_method_code: quote.shippingMethod().method_code,
                shipping_carrier_code: quote.shippingMethod().carrier_code
                }
            };

        fullscreenLoader.startLoader();

        return storage.post(
            urlManager.getUrlForSetShippingInformation(quote),
            JSON.stringify(payload)
        ).done(function (response) {

            if(removeTax) {
                response.totals.total_segments[2].value = -tax;
                response.totals.total_segments[4].value -= tax;
            } else {
                response.totals.total_segments[2].value = tax;
                response.totals.total_segments[4].value += tax;
            }

            var deferred = $.Deferred();
            totals.isLoading(true);

            getTotalsAction([], deferred);

            $.when(deferred).done(function () {
                quote.setTotals(response.totals);
                totals.isLoading(false);
                fullscreenLoader.stopLoader();
            });


        }).fail(function (response) {
            console.log('fail');
            totals.isLoading(false);
            fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();            
        });

    };
});
```

On the other hand I tried also to change the order totals by etc/sales.xml. Here I succeed to make the update on both frontend and admin order view, but I cannot manage to make these adjustments only after the validation of the VAT field. Here is my Model collect function:

```
public function collect(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
    ) {
        parent::collect($quote, $shippingAssignment, $total);
                $currentTax = $total->getTaxAmount();

                $total->setTaxAmount(-$currentTax);
                $total->setBaseTaxAmount(-$currentTax);

                $total->setGrandTotal($total->getGrandTotal() - $currentTax);
                $total->setBaseGrandTotal($total->getBaseGrandTotal() - $currentTax);


        return $this;
    }
```

So I tried to set a session message like this: $this->session->setMySession("Valid VAT"); in the controller where I am making the validation for the VAT and then in the Model to make the changes only if:

```
if($this->session->getMySession() == "Valid VAT" ){ 
               .........
}
```

but it doesn't set the session message because the Model is loading once with the first loading of the page and I cannot manage to reload it after the validation.

Can anyone help or guide how I can make the changes on prices only after the validation in the controller is made?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not using an observer to check if the field is valid and change totals before of after order save?

Comment: I tried to use an observer, but  when I am trying to update the totals by calling the collect method of the Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total\AbstractTotal class is not working fine